# How to convert bson to json in node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, bson

**How to convert bson to json in node.js?**

I'm checking the difference between two different obj, this shows an error because it wants JSON. (Data fatch from Mongodb)

I'm using below link fast-json-patch  but its not working.

[see difference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsondiffpatch)

[i am using this for bson to json](https://github.com/martindale/fast-json-patch)

```
   var job = objjob;
   var job2 = objreq; 
   var delta = diffpatcher.diff(job ,job2 );
   console.log(delta);
```

JOB1 BELOW DATA: I WANT TO COMPARE JOB 1 AND JOB 2

```
  [ { name: 'Tape',
        cost: 10,
        datetime: 2016-12-29T14:28:06.846Z,
        update_by: '',
        _id: 58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de26,
        image_path: null },  

     { name: 'Wire',
        cost: 100,
        datetime: 2016-12-29T14:28:06.845Z,
        update_by: '',
        _id: 58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de24,
        image_path: null } ]
```

JOB 2..

```
[ { image_path: null,
    _id: '58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de26',
    update_by: '',
    datetime: '2016-12-29T14:28:06.846Z',
    cost: 10,
    name: 'Tape',
    id: '58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de26' },

  { image_path: null,
    _id: '58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de24',
    update_by: '',
    datetime: '2016-12-29T14:28:06.845Z',
    cost: 100,
    name: 'Wire',
    id: '58651d762cd7d2f00cc2de24' } ]
```

Comment: `job` and `job2` are in bson?

Comment: yes dear ...one is request ..and other is fatch data from mongodb